# I have the following questions about transistors

Tags: transistors, diodes

1. Do transistors show diode action between all three leads?
2. Could an AVO meter be used to locate the base, emitter and collector of an amplifier?
3. What are diode ratings?
4. How can we differentiate between PNP and NPN transistors using an AVO meter?

Comment: One question per question post, please. Also, is this homework? If so you'll need to show what you know so far. Some more context is also necessary, e.g. for the third question.

Comment: no this in not a home work, i want to figure out if there is a way to differentiate between emiter and collector. i discussed it with my friend but seems like we werent able to conclude

Comment: the system was not letting me put one of my question per post. so i appolozie for putting them all togethar

Comment: 1. No. 2. No, but you can find the base; it's common to both diode junctions. 3. See any diode datasheet for its ratings. 4. The polarity of the base will tell you.

Comment: So what research you have tried to do yourself before asking? These are very common questions in homework assignments, so there should be a lot of material about it.

Comment: could you please elaborate it.

Comment: i have an exam two days from now so am preparing for that exam ☢

Comment: Some multimeters have a "transistor" function. So, it is easy to have some "specifications". Pin-out, type, and "beta".

Comment: i am not getting what you guys are talking about but anyways thank you so much

Comment: see this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-aEtFz-a3mA

Comment: aw thanku for sharing

Comment: OK, fine, so it's not homework but still a school assignment, which means, you just asked answer to your homework/school assignment/exam questions here without doing a reasonable effort yourself.

Comment: One question per question, please.

Comment: @Antonio51 I'm not sure AVO made any meters with that functionality. But funnily enough, they DID make a valve tester!

Comment: @user_1818839  Ok. I was just suggesting that even a low cost multimeter can do that. :-) now.

Answer (score 2):

I'll just take question 2 (the others are a matter of basic research and thinking which you really need to do yourself in order to have them register).  An AVO meter has two probes and the action differentiating a transistor from two separated diodes is only visible when looking on all three pins.

So the theoretical answer is "no" but there is a practical answer, too, which is "usually": you can engage all three pins by putting your AVO meter in "ohms" mode across C and E (you can at least distinguish them from B with simple measurements), then placing fingers between B and the purportive C.  This should display a lower resistance than you can achieve by just using your fingers alone, due to the transistor amplifying the current through your fingers.

Results can be somewhat iffish for power transistors which have comparatively small amplification factors.  Additionally, the typical damage mode for power transistors short of total failure is that their amplification factor drops (due to thermally caused concentration of currents in a small area that deteriorates in "secondary breakdown" which can burn actual holes into the semiconductor), and for detecting this loss of already modest hFE, the finger method is just too coarse.

Small-signal transistors are less likely to exhibit only partial failure to a degree where they don't do their job sufficiently, so the test is more helpful there as an integrity check.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Do transistors show diode action between all three leads?

There is diode action between emitter and base, and between collector and base. There  emitter and collector together do not act as a diode.

> 3. What are diode ratings?

That obviously depends upon the transistor in question. Since no particular model of transistor is specified, it is impossible to give an answer to this question.

> 4. How can we differentiate between PNP and NPN transistors using an AVO meter?

Assuming your AVO meter (i.e. multimeter) has a "diode" setting, and assuming you can test the transistor in isolation (i.e. not in a circuit) you can determine whether a transistor is PNP or NPN in two steps.

1. Determine which pin is the base. It is the only pin that will act as a diode with either of the other two pins when the third pin is open.
2. Determine whether the base is an cathode or a anode with respect to the other two pins. That is determine whether conventional current flows through the base toward each of the other two pins, or whether conventional current flows into the base from each of the other two pins. If conventional current flows through the base to the other two pins, the transistor is NPN. If conventional current flows from either of the other two pins into the base, then the transistor is PNP.

> 2. Could an AVO meter be used to locate the base, emitter and collector of an amplifier?

Distinguishing between emitter and collector will require other components (besides a multimeter / AVO meter). That is, you will need to make a primitive transistor testing circuit.

[user306434 has provided an interesting way to use the natural resistance of your fingers as an extra component to allow you to distinguish between the emitter and collector. Kudos to user306434!].